# Store only alternative lowest and highest values from a stream into an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, stream, double

I have a stream of decimal values coming from a continuous stream. These values start at a particular value going up to some maximum value then decreasing down to some minimum value(kind of like a wave). The maximum and minimum the values go are not always the same but the guaranteed thing is the values always go up then decrease then again go up and decrease and so on.

for example, the stream of values may look like:

```
  0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.2,
 1.1, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1,
 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5,
 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0 ...
```

The requirement I need is to store all the alternating lowest and highest values into an array.
So in the above sample, the final result array should be:

```
[0.3, 1.3, 0.0, 1.1, 0.0, ...]
```

This is the pseudo-code for the algorithm I tried for:

```
var x;
var arr = [];
//listen to stream
//on stream event
void onEvent(double val) {
  if (x == null) {
    x = val;
  }

  if (val > x) {
    if (arr.lastItem < val) {
      arr.push(val);
    }
  } else {
    if (arr.lastItem > val) {
      arr.push(val);
    }
  }
  x=val;
}
```

The final resulting arr is not the expected outcome.
What is the better solution?

Comment: Why would 0.3 come before 0.0? Shouldn't it be { 0.0, 1.3 } and { 0.3 and 1.1 }?

Comment: @Jason the stream can start with any value. But it goes up from the initial value.

Comment: @Jason The result stores the first value, then the next highest value, then the next lowest value, next highest value, next lowest value and so on

Comment: Okay, just re-read my apologies.

Comment: @Eritrean my preferred language is JavaScript. Sorry for the java tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const stream = [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.2,
  1.1, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1,
  0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5,
  0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0
];

const output = [];
let prevValue = null;
let isGoingUp = false;

function onEvent(value) {
  if (output.length < 2) {
    output.push(value);
    if (output.length === 2) {
      isGoingUp = output[0] < output[1];
      prevValue = value;
    }
    return;
  }
  if (isGoingUp) {
    if (value > prevValue) {
      output[output.length - 1] = value;
    } else if (value < prevValue) {
      output.push(value);
      isGoingUp = false;
    }
  } else {
    if (value < prevValue) {
      output[output.length - 1] = value;
    } else if (value > prevValue) {
      output.push(value);
      isGoingUp = true;
    }
  }
  prevValue = value;
}

stream.forEach(onEvent);

console.log(output);
```

What this does is to keep track if the stream is going up or down (the current value is bigger or smaller than the previous) and replace the last value in the output array when the stream is going down and the current value is smaller than the last value in the output or the stream is going up and the current value is bigger.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can be done much simpler but this is a solution. We simply create a while loop that continues while there are still values available. We then find the min and max values then remove them from the values list. We then create a new pair of min and max values. Once we have all min and max values we map them to an array of double values as you need.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.2,
                1.1, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1,
                0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8,
                0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0
        ));

        List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

        while (!values.isEmpty()) {
            Double min = values.stream().min(Double::compareTo)
                    .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);

            Double max = values.stream().max(Double::compareTo)
                    .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);

            pairs.add(new Pair(min, max));

            values.remove(min);
            values.remove(max);
        }
        double[] valuesSorted = pairs.stream()
                .map(pair -> new double[] { pair.getMin(), pair.getMax() })
                .flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream)
                .toArray();
    }

    static class Pair {

        private final double min;

        private final double max;

        Pair(double min, double max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public double getMin() {
            return min;
        }

        public double getMax() {
            return max;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pair{" +
                    "min=" + min +
                    ", max=" + max +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
[0.0, 1.3, 0.0, 1.2, 0.1, 1.2, 0.1, 1.1, 0.1, 1.1, 0.2, 1.1, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0, 0.3, 1.0, 0.3, 1.0, 0.3, 0.9, 0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 0.9, 0.4, 0.9, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0.7, 0.5, 0.7, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 0.6]
```

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: the result from your values should be `[0.3, 1.3, 0.0, 1.1, 0.0]`

Comment: By alternating I meant the crest and trough values from the wave the values form